# How do I write $y''+y' +\sin y \cos y = 0$ as a first order system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This would be fairly clear if $y = t$ where $t$ was the independent variable.

But I can not see how this can be done.

Comment: No $y$ being the independent variable would be a nonsense, as $y'=1$ and $y''=0$. Use $z=y'$.

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear I meant:  $y''+y' +\sin t \cos t = 0$, but this is not the question I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$z=y'=\frac{dy}{dt}$$
and then
$$y''=\frac d{dt}\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}=z\frac{dz}{dy}$$
so the equation can be rewritten as
$$z\frac{dz}{dy}+z+\sin y\cos y=0,$$
a first order equation in $z$ and $y.$ This trick is useful when the independent variable is absent in the original equation.